# How to execute sweet alert after page completes reloading

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

```
location.reload();
      $( document ).ready(function() {
         swal({
        title: 'Deleted!',
        text: 'Your post has been deleted',
        type: 'success',
        timer: 2000
      });
      });
```

my problem is the page reloads while sweet alert is shown.
how do I make it so it waits until the page reloads complete before showing the sweet alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this. In your html while rendiring do the following (you can also wrap this in an if statements if you want to show sweetlert based upon some condition):

```
<div class="hidden" id="alertUser">
    <p id="header-message">Failed</p>
    <p id="main-message">An Error Occured While Updating Doctor Recrod..!!!</p>
    <p id="alert-type">warning</p>
    <p id="confirm-button-class">btn-warning</p>
</div>
```

and in your script just do the following:

```
window.onload = function () {
    showUserAlerts();
}

function showUserAlerts()
{
    var $isEditSuccessfull = $("div#alertUser");

    if ($isEditSuccessfull.length > 0) {
        var headerMessage = $isEditSuccessfull.find("p#header-message").text();
        var mainMessage = $isEditSuccessfull.find("p#main-message").text();
        var alertType = $isEditSuccessfull.find("p#alert-type").text();
        var confirmButtonClass = $isEditSuccessfull.find("p#confirm-button-class").text();

        swal({
            title: headerMessage,
            text: mainMessage,
            type: alertType,
            confirmButtonClass: confirmButtonClass
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.